# what is the value of $p$ and $q$?

Tags: real-analysis

> let $f(x) = \begin{cases} arc \tan(px+q) , \text{ x}<0  \\ \frac {\pi}{4} e^{\sin qx}, x \ge 0 \end{cases}$
>
> Find all the  value  of $p$  and $q$   such that  $f$ is differentiable

My  try : we have   $f'(0) ^- =   \frac{\tan^{-1}(px + q) - \tan^{-1}q}{x-0}$

$f'(0)^{+} = \frac{\frac {\pi}{4} e^{\sin qx} - \frac {\pi}{4}}{ x-0}$

We  know  that  for  differentiable  $f'(0)^ + = f'(0)^-$

$$\frac{\tan^{-1}(px + q) - \tan^{-1}q}{x-0}= \frac{\frac {\pi}{4} e^{\sin qx} - \frac {\pi}{4}}{ x-0}$$

$$\tan^{-1}( \frac{px}{ 1+ (px+q)q})=\frac{\pi}{4} (e^{\sin qx} -1)$$

After im not able  to proceed  further

Any hint/solution  will be  appreciated

Comment: Are $arc\tan$ and $\tan^{-1}$ the same function?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i thinks  same

Comment: You *think*? You wrote the question and you don't know?!

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ is the inverse of $\tan(x)$ @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find $(p,q)$ such that $f$ is continuous in $0$:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\tan^{-1}(q)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\frac{\pi}{4},
$$
so $q=1$. Then find $p$ such that $f$ is differentiable in 0:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{p}{1+(px+q)^2}=\frac{p}{1+q^2}=\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\pi}{4}e^{\sin(qx)}\cos(qx)q=\frac{\pi}{4}q
$$
substitute $q=1$ and solve in $p$.

Comment: thanks u @ sorva

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

You forgot $ \lim $ !

We have

$f'(0) ^- =  \lim_{x \to 0-} \frac{\tan^{-1}(px + q) - \tan^{-1}q}{x-0}$

and

$f'(0)^{+} = \lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\frac {\pi}{4} e^{\sin qx} - \frac {\pi}{4}}{ x-0}$

Can you proceed ?